# How do I sync my forked repo with Original repo without affecting the changes in forked repo in Gitlab

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitlab, repository

I have a repo 2 which is forked from repo 1. I have already made changes to repo 2 and they are in good shape in the master branch of repo 2. Now I need to get the latest changes from repo 1 to forked repo 2 without affecting the changes that I have made. How do I do this in a best way either in gitlab or VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

One best practice is to create new branches in your fork, as to avoid conflicts with upstream changes. That way, sync processes from upstream will always succeed. You can read about syncing your fork in the GitLab blog [how to keep your fork up to date with its origin](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/12/01/how-to-keep-your-fork-up-to-date-with-its-origin/).

Eventually, your changes will need to be merged into an upstream branch. If you made modifications that conflict with changes made in upstream branches, those conflicts will eventually need to be resolved. This process is no different for forks than it is for local diverged branches -- you can merge the branches and, if necessary, make any commits necessary to resolve any conflicts that may arise.